# the difference between execv and execve

Tags: c, linux, exec

Iv'e tried to search in google but didn't really understand what is the difference between `execv`, `execve`, `execlp`.

If there is anyone can help me I'll be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp

With execve() you can specify the environment to the new process image with the env argument. The env argument is the last argument passed to the execve() call. The execv() call cannot specify the env argument. Finally, with execclp, you specify a filename rather than a path and the PATH environment variable is used to search for the executable.

Answer (score 4):

Among those 3 functions `execv` is the simplest one: it has all arguments in a vector, however you must give the **exact** path to the executable.

Now, `execve` adds the possibility to access the system environment: the variables defined there. For example if you define `MY_VAR=42`, using `execve` this definition is visible in the code using `getenv`.

Finally, `execlp` allows you to only give the name of the executable and it will be searched in the `PATH` variable.

Comment: if you don't mine you can give any examples for that